# Error message popping up even though I have added the driver location to my PATH

Tags: bash, macos, path, webdriver

Im really new to python so if anyone could explain this issue to me with a fix it is much appreciated!!

I have created a web scraping bot using python and selenium, however, I am faced with this error and I think it has got to do with my Path and chrome driver.
This is the error I'm faced with:

```
/Users/jonathan/venvs/env310/bin/python3.10 "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 64298 --file /Users/jonathan/PycharmProjects/Seleniumlearning/BBDC_fullauto.py
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py:1844: DeprecationWarning: currentThread() is deprecated, use current_thread() instead
  dummy_thread = threading.currentThread()
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.5284.44)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathan/venvs/env310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jonathan/venvs/env310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 84, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
python-BaseException
```

Thus, in order to try and fix it...

I read an online tutorial on how to change your path using vi ~/.bash_profile, and have added the file containing my chrome driver (~/drivers) using the code `export PATH=$PATH:~/drivers`.

```
> export PATH=$PATH:~/drivers  Setting PATH for Python 3.10
> # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> ~                                                                     
> "~/.bash_profile" 4L, 184B
```

After that, I proceeded to `source ~/.bash_profile` but it gave me this message - `/Users/jonathan/.bash_profile:2: command not found: Setting`. Apparently, in the tutorial, this message isn't supposed to come up and its to refresh the page

However, I could still see the path to my driver being added when I echo $PATH:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jonathan/drivers

So, since I added it already, why does it still give me the error mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `#` before your comment: `# Setting PATH for..`

You were seeing directories in your path from when you previously sourced this file. Try exiting and restarting the terminal emulator.